# SVM gamma parameter influence : 2moons data set

Tags: r, svm, data-mining, kernel-trick, parameterization

I'm working on the two-moons data set, in which we can achieve a perfect discrimination, the classes are separable. I'm using the RBF kernel, and as a consequence, i have to tune the gamma parameter. I noticed that, when gamma is very small, the number of vector support is very important, and the separation will be linear. On the contrary, when gamma will be high (10 for instance), there will be less vector support, and the seperation will fit quasi perfectly. Let me show you what i get :

[image: High Gamma = 10]

[image: Low gamma = 0.1]

I made some researches. I found that for small values of gamma = high variance (vice versa).
"When gamma is very small, the model is too constrained and cannot capture the complexity or “shape” of the data. The region of influence of any selected support vector would include the whole training set. The resulting model will behave similarly to a linear model with a set of hyperplanes that separate the centers of high density of any pair of two classes."

I'm not sure understanding everything. Does it say that, for small values of gamma, we will have a lot of vector support, then they will all have the same influence, and tend to "repulse" each other, to create a linear separation?

"If gamma is too large, the radius of the area of influence of the support vectors only includes the support vector itself and no amount of regularization with C will be able to prevent overfitting."

Again, not sure to understand. I read that when we have a large value of gamma, the vector support will have a strong influence on point which are close to them. No? I'm a bit lost. Moreover, i kind of see the overfitting, but ...

Thank you for your help. I read a lot of post about that, but it's still not clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increasing $C$ the cost parameter reduces the number of support vectors.

Increasing $\gamma$ usually increases the number of support vectors (though I am less sure about this observation).

With only two support vectors, your decision boundary will be the bisector of the segment defined by the two support vectors. I am not surprised by the shape of the decision boundary of the second figure, which cannot capture exotic decision boundaries.

However, what makes a large $\gamma$ able to capture the complexity of various datasets is the small bandwith around each point. Therefore, with a lot of support vectors and a small bandwith, you can achieve a 100% accuracy on your training data (which is usually a bad sign).

[The following video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QRZzKHt_rHk) shows the influence of $\gamma$ on simple data sets (disclaimer, I just uploaded it).

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer and your video!

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer and your video!  i'm reading this link [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_rbf_parameters.html) and i'm having trouble understanding something. At the end, they explain that gamma is good to regularize. They saw that, for intermediate values of gamma, they had a model as good as when the value of C was high. They explain that it's not necessary to limit the number of vector support. What does that mean?